# How can I add a text to?

Tags: python

i am trying to add a text to my output

```
def as():

      a = 0
        return a


def d():
    return d
```

Comment: `d` is a list, not a dictionary. Also, you `return` on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: yes by mistake i changed return's position but still i dont know what to put in d??

Comment: What happens when a value repeats or the value is not hashable?

Comment: well i have a problem when the value repeats i dont understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a list for some reason instead of a dictionary.
Use generator to reverse key/value pairs:

```
def index_by_author(f):
    from library import load_library
    return {value: key for key, value in load_library().items()}
```

Comment: thanks i got an error in 'function' object has no attribute 'items'?

Comment: it should to have if it's a dictionary

Comment: down-voters, do you care to write a comment?

Comment: it is a dictionary and i already finished the load_library and its working

Comment: but index_by_author has an error in items

Comment: can you show me the whole code?

Comment: def load_library(f):

    with open(f,'rt') as x:
        return dict(map(str.strip, line.split("|")) for line in x)

Comment: i didn't know it was a function, i updated my answer

Comment: i would also recommend to make imports at the top of your py file, not inside the function

Comment: thanks now it works but the problem that the value has 2 similar in the dictionary ......

Comment: (Foundation|Asimov, Isaac)
(Foundation and Empire|Asimov, Isaac)
(Second Foundation|Asimov, Isaac)
(Dune|Herbert, Frank)
(Children of Dune|Herbert, Frank)
(RUR|Capek, Karel)
(2001: A Space Odyssey|Clarke, Arthur C.)
(2010: Odyssey Two|Clarke, Arthur C.)

Comment: it doesn't care if any other key/value pairs are similar, it will invert every key/value pair

Comment: yes as you said but the automatic check got   invalid file: {}

Comment: we are not dealing with any files in index_by_author, btw what is f parameter which you supply for a function, but never use?

Comment: it is a file 'books.txt' which is provided automatically by the automatic check

Comment: i don't know what the automatic check is

Comment: oh i see what you mean, you need to provide your file name as a string in the load_library function, i thought it was obvious since you wrote it

Comment: yes exactly , is it possible to change the {} to a list or tuple because its not accepting the {}

Comment: i tried but its not working

Comment: can you update your question with everything you have, it's not quite obvious what you're trying to achive

Comment: i just edited my question

Comment: ok, instead of f you need to provide a real file name as a string with path if it's not in the same folder. So keep use it like this {value:key for key, value in load_library('any_file.txt').items()}

Comment: still the same error i think its not accepting the {} i dont understand it

Comment: you need to provide a file name like this: 'file.txt' why do you try to put {} instead?

Comment: yes i provided the 'file.txt' but it says with open(f,'rt') as x:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'books.txt'

Comment: It supposed to be in the same location as your script

Comment: yes i think theres something wrong with the automatic check but when i test it in pycharm i got two lists of the same solution?

Comment: it works from the cli and any ide, i don't know what the automatic check is

Comment: yes i will check with my tutor , thank you very much you really helped me :)

Comment: by the way you don't have to do that from library import load_library if both functions in the same py file

Comment: yes when i removed it i got one list but still its not working with the automatic check :(